# UITableViewCell generating exception on setting text on cell item

Tags: uitableview, nsdictionary

I am using following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath, when i am filling data in UILabel it is sending error

```
NSDictionary *benchmarkDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[benchmarkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:15]).text = [benchmarkDictionary objectForKey:@"benchmarkTitle"];
((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:16]).text = [benchmarkDictionary objectForKey:@"benchmarkDescription"];
```

Exception is:
-[Benchmark objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75d59c0
2013-03-08 16:21:39.515 Fdtrainer[2719:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Benchmark objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75d59c0'

My Benchmark class is:

```
@interface Benchmark : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *benchmarkTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *benchmarkDescription;

-(id)initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder;
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;

@end

@implementation Benchmark

@synthesize bid;
@synthesize benchmarkTitle;
@synthesize benchmarkDescription;

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        bid = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"id"];
        benchmarkTitle = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"benchmarkTitle"];
        benchmarkDescription = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"benchmarkDescription"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:bid forKey:@"id"];
    [encoder encodeObject:benchmarkTitle forKey:@"benchmarkTitle"];
    [encoder encodeObject:benchmarkDescription forKey:@"benchmarkDescription"];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are accessing your properties in wrong way :

Try this :

```
@interface Benchmark : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *benchmarkTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *benchmarkDescription;

-(id)initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder;
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;

@end

@implementation Benchmark

@synthesize bid = _bid;
@synthesize benchmarkTitle = _benchmarkTitle;
@synthesize benchmarkDescription = _benchmarkDescription;

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

self = [super init];
if(self) {
    _bid = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"id"];
    _benchmarkTitle = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"benchmarkTitle"];
    _benchmarkDescription = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"benchmarkDescription"];
}
return self;
}

- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

[encoder encodeObject:_bid forKey:@"id"];
[encoder encodeObject:_benchmarkTitle forKey:@"benchmarkTitle"];
[encoder encodeObject:_benchmarkDescription forKey:@"benchmarkDescription"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the following line might be causing issue.

```
NSDictionary *benchmarkDictionary = (NSDictionary *)[benchmarkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Are you sure benchmarkArray contains NSDictionary inside it.  Casting something to NSDictionary won't make it one.  It seems like benchmarkArray contains Benchmark objects, which is of type NSObject and they do not respond to objectForKey selector.